# Traduccion para "as far as I can tell" / Translation for "as far as I can tell"

Tags: traducción, modismos, expresiones-fijas

## Español

Como hispanoparlante nativo y, yo considero, con un alto nivel en el manejo del Inglés, varias veces tengo dificultad para traducir expresiones de uso común y me acaba de pasar cuando quise agregar la versión en Español de una pregunta en nuestro foro.

"As far as I can tell" la he traducido de diferentes formas y de alguna forma como que no me siento muy convencido de que le he atinado. Mis intentos han sido:

- Hasta donde sé
- Hasta donde entiendo
- Lo que yo creo (el "yo" lo uso para dar énfasis al hecho de que es mi opinión)

Según yo, cualquiera de los tres es correcto, pero no puedo evitar pensar que puede haber una mejor traducción para la frase.

¿Cuál sería la traducción correcta?

---

## English

As a native Spanish speaker and, what I consider, a person with high English speaking skills, I sometimes have a hard time translating common expressions and it just happened to me when I tried to add the Spanish version for a question on the site.

I have translated "as far as I can tell" in a few different ways and I do not feel I have nailed it. These have been my attempts:

- Hasta donde sé
- Hasta donde entiendo
- Lo que yo creo (in this case the "yo", which is "I" is used to give more emphasis to the fact that it is my belief.)

As far as I can tell (no pun intended), any one of these three is correct but, I cannot help but think that there has to be a better translation for this expression.

Which could that be?

Comment: The translation of your question seems to be "Según yo cualquiera".  I suppose you could add that to your list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Efectivamente, las que has pensado están bien, incluso a las dos primeras les puedes añadir el "yo" para enfatizar que es tu opinión personal:

> - Hasta donde yo sé
> - Hasta donde yo entiendo

Las frases alternativas que buscas pueden ser:

> - Según veo (yo)
> - Según tengo entendido / Hasta donde tengo entendido
> - Por lo que yo sé

Incluso puedes usar una traducción más literal de la expresión inglesa sin que tenga que ser un calco de ella, puesto que es ampliamente usada y tiene mucho sentido:

> - Hasta donde yo puedo decir

Comment: "Según tengo entendido" me parece una traducción muy precisa y elegante. "Hasta donde yo sé" está bien, pero "hasta donde yo entiendo" no me suena natural. Otra posibilidad es "por lo que yo sé".

Comment: @Albertus buena "por lo que yo sé", la añado.

Answer (score 0):

Para agregar a la lista -> hasta donde tengo entendido | según me parece / se / veo / creo

No creo que halla una traducción exacta, diferente seria la cosa si la frase fuera "As far as I know..."

En my opinión "As far as I can tell ..." es una frase usada cuando elaboramos/expresamos una opinión, muchas veces sobre algo en el pasado (lejano o cercano).

No obstante cabe remarcar que tell es mejor vista como contar

tell me a story -> cuéntame una historia

"lo que te puedo contar" y "hasta donde yo te puedo contar" no serian unas traducciones muy utilizadas, aun así mantienen o dan a entender algo similar.

Mucha gente usa por ejemplo "lo mas que te puedo decir/contar" pero este es un termino el cual solo he escuchado en Uruguay .